# Travis CI : Possible to speed up or cache "g++-4.8"?

Tags: travis-ci

Is it possible to speed up or cache `g++-4.8` install in Travis CI?
It always spent more than two minutes like this [image]

This is my .travis.yml :

```
{
  "language": "node_js",
  "node_js": "6.10.0",
  "env": "CXX=g++-4.8",
  "addons": {
    "apt": {
      "sources": [
        "ubuntu-toolchain-r-test"
      ],
      "packages": [
        "g++-4.8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": [
    "npm install"
  ]
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise",
  "os": "linux"
}
```